# My express validation returns errors even when the form is correctly filled

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

I have been battling with this for some time now, I have this Nodejs Express app and my registration form returns a bunch of validation errors when the form fields are invalid which is a good thing but however, when the form is properly filled it still returns these errors and doesn't submit any data.

This is the code route.post for register

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
var password2 = req.body.password2;

// Check for image field
if(req.files && req.files.profileimage){
    console.log('Uploading File...');

    // File Info
    var profileImageOriginalName    = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
    var profileImageName            = req.files.profileimage.name;
    var profileImageMime            = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
    var profileImagePath            = req.file.profileimage.path;
    var profileImageExt             = req.files.profileimage.extension;
    var profileImageSize            = req.files.profileimage.size;

}else {
    // Set a Default Image
    var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
}

// Form validation
req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid Email ID').isEmail();
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password field is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2', 'Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);

// Check for Validation errors
var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
    res.render('register', {
        errors: errors,
        name: name,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        password2: password2
    });
}else {
    var newUser = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        profileimage: profileImageName
    });

    // Create User
    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });

    // Success Message
    req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and may log in');

    res.location('/');
    res.redirect('/');
}
});
```

And here is my register.jade code

```
extends layout
block content
    h1 Register
    p Please register using the form below
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
    form(method='post', action='/users/register', enctype='multipart/form-data')
        .form-group
            label Name
            input.form-control(name='name', type='text', placeholder='Enter Name')
        .form-group
            label Email
            input.form-control(name='email', type='text', placeholder='Enter Email')
        .form-group
            label Username
            input.form-control(name='username', type='text', placeholder='Enter Username')
        .form-group
            label Password
            input.form-control(name='password', type='password', placeholder='Enter Password')
        .form-group
            label Confirm Password
            input.form-control(name='password2', type='password', placeholder='Confirm Password')
        .form-group
            label Profile Image
            input.form-control(name='profileimage', type='file')
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', value='Register')
```

Please any help would be so much appreciated... thanks

Comment: What errors are returned? What library are you using for validation?

Comment: These errors are returned in flash message and I use express-validators
req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid Email ID').isEmail();
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password field is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2', 'Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);

Comment: Em, can you console log the errors to see what's wrong?

Comment: There are no errors on the console... looks good on there

Comment: Log the `errors` object to see why it's not empty.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that I just started learning node, do you mind telling me how? please

Comment: Do `console.log(errors)` before `if` clause to see what's inside.

Comment: ok i found these

`[ { param: 'name', msg: 'Name is required', value: undefined },
  { param: 'email', msg: 'Email is required', value: undefined },
  { param: 'email', msg: 'Invalid Email ID', value: undefined },
  { param: 'username',
    msg: 'Username is required',
    value: undefined },
  { param: 'password',
    msg: 'Password field is required',
    value: undefined },
  { param: 'password2',
    msg: 'Password do not match',
    value: undefined } ]
`

Comment: Do you use a `body-parser` module to parse the request at all?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I did that in my app.js file and here's the code

`// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
`

Comment: and it was right above my sessions and my app.use routes

Comment: The thing is that `body-parser` doesn't support `multipart/form-data` forms. You should use `multer` or another library to handle multiparts

Comment: actually I'm using multer for my file uploads and the only place I used part is the enctype attribute of the form which is enctype='multipart/form-data'. what do you think?

Comment: Body parser won't work with multipart form, which means that the `req.body` will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for time, I finally figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body parser doesn't work with multipart form attribute set to form-data, but instead set to urlencoded which is this

```
<form action="/register" method="post" multipart="urlencoded"></form>
```

with that you should be good! Thank you all for your time. stay blessed

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Use body parser and express-validator before router you used
2) if you use multipart/form-data then you use validator middleware after multer file upload strategy
```

this is work form me

```
var validator = function(req,res,next){
  req.checkBody('name').notEmpty().withMessage('Name field is required');
}

router.post('/upload',multer.single('avatar'),validator,function(req,res,next){
  //req.body
  //req.file 
 both object available here 
})
```